# C# Threading Read Write locks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Hi what will be the cleanest solution for the following pattern ?

Given a class for Read and Write some file/resouce, providing already implemented "read()" and "write()" functions. Create a "Read()" and "Write()" function that would wrap the "read()" and "write()"and prevent threads from interfering as follows:

a. multiple threads are allowed to Read

b. Only one thread is allowed to Write - so if a thread is already writing the other threads must wait.

c. writing must be prevented while a thread is reading and vice versa

Comment: Use ReaderWriteLock or ReaderWriteLockSlim.

Comment: Do your own homework. If you have a *specific* question about *actual code*, post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) as the most efficient construct.

Quote from MSDN:

> ReaderWriterLockSlim is similar to ReaderWriterLock, but it has simplified rules for recursion and for upgrading and downgrading lock state. ReaderWriterLockSlimavoids many cases of potential deadlock. In addition, the performance of ReaderWriterLockSlim is significantly better than ReaderWriterLock. ReaderWriterLockSlim is recommended for all new development.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, there's already a well-established pattern to solve this - [reader-writer locks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). This pattern works exactly how you describe - at any given time, you can have *either* an arbitrary number of readers *or* a single writer.

The .NET Framework [already has an implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx) of this pattern.